# jQuery open dialog in child window prevents toggle, hide, or show in main window

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have an older codebase in which the last page of a lengthy process has a results page, with some accordion-style controls, and a "print this" button that opens a printer-friendly version of the same report. When the printer-friendly page opens, it automatically brings up the print dialog.

Once the dialog is open, in a new tab, if the user is using Chrome, the user can switch back to the original tab, but the toggle button no longer works. jQuery `hide` and `show` functions no longer function either. Instead, they seem to be queued, but delayed. Once the user switches back to the child tab, and either closes the print dialog, or closes the tab, then all the toggle, hide, and show function calls take place in a back-to-back manner.

This may seem like an edge case, but I need to know if there is a way to either prevent the child window from blocking functionality in the parent window, to disable controls until the print dialog has been closed, or to disable controls until the child tab has been closed.

Here is a sample code to demonstrate the problem:

```
<html><head></head><body>

<!-- Accordion content below. -->
<div id="div1">
            Here is our content<br />
            to be displayed.<br />
            Part of the issue becomes<br />
            more apparent when<br />
            several lines are<br />
            present.<br />
            Lorem Ipsum...<br />
            Lorem Ipsum...<br />
            Lorem Ipsum...<br />
            Lorem Ipsum...<br />
</div>

<!-- Our collapse/hide button. Will not work when print dialog is open 
     in child tab. -->
<button id="btn1">Show/Hide Content</button>

<!-- Our print button -->
<div><a href="test.php?print=true" target="_blank">Print in New Tab</a></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // When the button is clicked, show/hide content
    $('#btn1').on("click", function() {
        $('#div1').toggle("slow");
    });

    // Flag used to determine whether we print this page. Pretend that there 
    // is more print-unfriendly cruft that would be removed if this were the 
    // print-friendly page. 
    var do_print = false

    // if the ?print=true request variable has been appended to the url,
    // trigger javascript that brings up the print dialog.
    <?php if(isset($_REQUEST['print'])) :?>
        do_print=true;
    <?php endif ?>

    if( do_print==true ) {
        window.print();
    }

</script>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I know after searching around, it's a bug of Chrome, blocking all the code using `setInterval` and `setTimeout`. The animation of `toggle` uses `setInterval`, so it is blocked.
There are several ways to workaround this problem:

1. Use `.toggle` without parameter, animation is not used.
2. Disable buttons on main page, optionally show a message telling users that this page is not active until the print dialog is closed, by adding this code:

   ```
   // When the button is clicked, show/hide content
   $('#btn1').on("click", function() {
       $('#div1').toggle("slow");
   });
   window.disableBtns = function () {
     // Optionally show some warning message
     $('#btn1').attr('disabled', true)
     console.log('disable');
   };
   window.enableBtns = function () {
     $('#btn1').attr('disabled', false)
     console.log('enable');
   };

   // Flag used to determine whether we print this page. Pretend that there 
   // is more print-unfriendly cruft that would be removed if this were the 
   // print-friendly page. 
   var do_print = false

   // if the ?print=true request variable has been appended to the url,
   // trigger javascript that brings up the print dialog.
   <?php if(isset($_REQUEST['print'])) :?>
       do_print=true;
   <?php endif ?>

   if( do_print==true ) {
       opener.disableBtns();
       window.print();
       opener.enableBtns();
   }
   ```